# Understanding Wikipedia's definition of the "join" of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am speaking about the second statement of the definition given below (from Wikipedia's ["Join (topology)" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)#Topological_spaces)):

> [image]

My questions are:

1-Since in AT book by Allen Hatcher, the definition of the join was stated as all line segments joining points in $A$ to points in $B,$ but in the second given definition, the identification is identifying points in $A$ with points in $A$ also and same for $B$, which sounds unintuitive for me, specifically, we have $(a_1, b, 1) \sim (a_2, b, 1)$ and $(a, b_1, 0) \sim (a, b_2, 0).$

2- Also, why when the point $b_1$ is identified with $b_2$ we have 0 while when the point $a_1$ is identified with $a_2$ we have 1?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: It may be helpful to break $[0,1]$ into $[0,1/2]\cup[1/2,1]$ and think of this as the mapping cylinders of the projections $A\times B\to A$ and $A\times B\to B$ glued along the free ends of the cylinders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join of two topological spaces is space that inherits some of the properties of each space, which somehow *interpolates* from one to the other as the parameter $t$ varies along $[0, 1]$. The most visually intuitive way that I have found to picture it is to imagine the product of the two spaces *extruded* (multiplied by the parameter interval), then one space is *pinched* together on one end and the other space is pinched down to a point on the other.

At each endpoint of the interval, there is a homeomorphic copy of one or the other space. If you want a copy of space $A$ at $t=0$, then you need to collapse the coordinates in $B$ to a single point. Analogously on the other end of the join space, if you want a copy of $B$ at $t=1$, then you need to collapse the coordinates in $A$ to a single point.

To understand this *collapsing* (using the projection map as a quotient), notice that the projection $A \times B \to A$ sending $(a, b) \mapsto a$ can be equivalently thought of as a quotient map $A \times B \to (A \times B)/{\sim}$, where the equivalence relation identifies
$$
(a, b_1) \sim (a, b_2) 
\quad \text{for any $a \in A$, any $b_1, b_2 \in B$.}
$$
This identification relies on the canonical homeomorphism $A \to A \times \{*\}$, where $\{*\}$ is a one-point space that results from identifying all the points in $B$ to one another.

Comment: Is there a difference between "Pinched together" and "Pinched down" in the first paragraph?